# Overlaying 2 DataSeries plots with same index

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have extracted the 2015 temperature data and created 2 DataSeries for record breaking highs and lows (df_2015_max, and df_2015_min), where df_min and _max are record lows and highs over a 10 year period. These Series have 37 and 32 values, respectively.

```
df_2015_min = df_2015_min[df_2015_min < df_min]
df_2015_max = df_2015_max[df_2015_max > df_max]
```

I have then reindexed those series to match the index of df_min and _max, which are the minimum and maximum temperatures. So I have NaN values wherever the record is not broken.

```
df_2015_max.reindex(df_max.index)
df_2015_min.reindex(df_min.index)
```

I thought that if I plot these to the existing plot it will automatically index it correctly, but this doesn't happen, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
plt.figure()

#plot data
ax1 = df_min.plot(label = "_nolegend_")
ax2 = df_max.plot(label = "_nolegend_")
df_2015_max.plot(marker = "o", label ="Record Breaking High", ax = ax2, linestyle = "none")
df_2015_min.plot(marker = "o", label ="Record Breaking Low", ax = ax1, linestyle = "none")


#fill_between data
plt.gca().fill_between(range(365), df_min, df_max, facecolor = "purple", alpha = 0.1)

#set axes labels and figure title

plt.title("Temperature record highs and lows (2004 - 2015) in °C")

#set xticks
plt.tick_params(left='off', bottom='on', labelleft='on', labelbottom='on')
ax1.set_xticks(range(0,360, 30)) #set approximate ticks for months in a year

#list comprehension, take each month from a year and format it as abbreviation (%b)
ax1.set_xticklabels([datetime(2010,i,1).strftime('%b') for i in range(1,13)]) 

#add legend
plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

But the results plot the values from the year start and not on corresponding dates:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPY84.png)

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the mistake was not reindexing in-place:

```
df_2015_max = df_2015_max.reindex(df_max.index)
df_2015_min = df_2015_min.reindex(df_min.index)
```

fixed it.